# Android is ignoring my choice of lock screen

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, lock-screens

I have bought a Samsung Galaxy S5 and I was so excited about the fingerprint feature. 
So when  I got  the phone I tried to set fingerprint as my unlock method, but it didn't work. 
The lockscreen now has a pedlock and there is two ways to unlock the phone.

First way:
Drag over the screen (the default option).

Second way:
Drag over the pedlock to get to a new screen from which I can only open with fingerprint.

How can I fix this?
I want to unlock the phone only with fingerprint, not with drag.

Comment: Question is too confusing to understand. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: @MANI Now I have changed the question.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! The problem was that when I connected my Samsung Gear Fit to my phone via bluetooth the phone was told to bypass lockscreen. The solution was to go to Settings > Security > Trusted Agents and then turn Smart Lock off :)